# Changing setimeout delay time while its running

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs6

I would like to change Or update the setimeout delay time while it's running. I have verified by using debounceTime() as an alternate. But need to find how to update the ulready mentioned delay time.instead of creating new.

In the above code snippet I have mentioned the delay as 10 sec. But my need is after this settimeout is started when a mouseevent is triggered I need to update the delay time while settimeout is running.

Kindly advise. Thanks

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: im not sure thats doable since they setTimout will be registerd in the event loop , so you have to cancel the previous one and set a new one

Comment: Please __add the code__ mentioned (`above code snippet`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Timer class` to help. Please see the below `implementation`.
`Timer.start` to start the timer. if you want to change some data and `re-run`. Then use `Timer.interrupt`. It will take delta and run the function again. You can modify your logic.

```js
class Timer {
  constructor(cb, ms = 2000) {
    this._ms = ms;
    this.ms = ms;
    this.cb = cb;
    this.timer = null;
    this.startedAt = null;
  }
  start() {
    this.startedAt = new Date().getTime();
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    console.log("started");
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.cb();
    }, this._ms);
  }
  intrupt() {
    const timeSpends = new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt;
    const timeLeft = this.ms - timeSpends;
    if (timeLeft > 0) {
      this._ms = timeLeft;
      this.start();
    }
  }
}
console.time("TIME");
let counter = 0;
const timer = new Timer(() => {
  console.timeEnd("TIME");
  console.log("counter: ", counter);
});

timer.start();
setTimeout(function cancel() {
  counter++;
  timer.intrupt();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you @xdeepakv . If it's a list of messages  which are calling one by one can i able to stop each message fade .